# Работа с array_intersect в PHP

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

Есть бесконечное число N массивов в массиве.
В этих массивах также есть неопределённое количество элементов.
Общий массив выглядит примерно вот так:

```
$users = [
     0 => [3,5,1,4],
     1 => [9,2,7,0,1],
     2 => [11,6,8,1]
];
```

Мне нужно вытащить общие элементы в массиве. (В данном случае это 1)
Также нужно вытащить общий элемент в такой ситуации:

```
$users = [
     0 => [3,5,1,4],
     1 => [9,2,7,0,1],
     2 => [11,6,8,13]
];
```

Виден общий элемент между первыми двумя ключами (Должно выдать также 1)

array_intersect тут не помошник... (Так как аргументы не двумерные массивы)
Приведу пример для чего это нужно... Есть высоконагруженные беседы в вк.
Их около 600 штук. Нужно вычислять тех пользователей которые
уже состоят в двух беседах или в трех беседах и т.д.

Comment: Т.е. найти любые элементы, которые встречаются в более, чем одном массиве?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слейте все массивы в один, отсортируйте и найдите стоящие рядом одинаковые идентификаторы

```
$data = [];
foreach ($users as $user)
  $data = array_merge($data, $user);
sort($data);

$prev = null;
$cnt = 1;
$dups = [];
foreach($data as $idx) {
  if (isset($prev) && $idx == $prev) {
    $cnt++;
    if ($cnt === 2)
      $dups[] = $idx;
  } else {
    $cnt = 1;
    $prev = $idx;
  }
}
var_dump($dups);
```

**Update**

Или можно вызвать функцию `array_count_values()` для общего массива и посмотреть для каких ключей значение будет больше 1. Какой способ быстрее - нужно проверять

```
$data = [];
foreach ($users as $user)
  $data = array_merge($data, $user);
$counts = array_count_values($data);
$dups = [];
foreach($counts as $key => $val) {
  if ($val > 1)
    $dups[] = $key;
}
var_dump($dups);
```

Comment: Для временного решения пойдёт, но пока костыль. Ибо в дальнейшем планируется сравнивать не только цифровые элементы, но и строковые. Но всё же спасибо. Хорошая идея

Comment: Нет никакой проблемы сравнивать и числовые и строковые переменные

Comment: отсортировать строковые элементы если там указаны не числа нельзя

Comment: Кто вам сказал такую глупость? https://ideone.com/xnPAqQ

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал что PHP так умеет) Но всё это очень похоже на костыль... Явно должен быть способ низкоуровневый, написанный на PHP (Про встроенные функции в php говорю)

Comment: Ну вот вам на стандартной функции